# Itextsharp SetField not replacing the text as expected in mail attachment .Net C# core

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, memorystream

I have a pdf template with below content

```
First Name: {{FirstName}}
Contact Number: {{ContactNumber}}
Email Id: {{EmailId}}
Address 1: {{Address1}}
Address 2: {{Address2}}
Qualification: {{Qualification}}
```

Using itextsharp i need to replace the texts which is inside the curly braces to its actual texts. So for that i have coded like this

```
                    string formFile = path;

                    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formFile);
                    MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
                    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream);
                    AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

                    fields.SetField("{{FirstName}}", objUser.FirstName);
                    fields.SetField("{{ContactNumber}}", objUser.EmailId);
                    fields.SetField("{{Address1}}", objUser.AddressLine1);
                    fields.SetField("{{Address2}}", objUser.AddressLine2);
                    fields.SetField("{{Qualification}}", objUser.Education);
                    fields.SetField("{{AppNumber}}", "01A2021"+objUser.UserId.ToString());

                    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

                    stamper.FormFlattening = true;
                    stamper.Close();

                    stream.Position = 0;
```

and then created my email attachment using

```
                    System.Net.Mime.ContentType contentType = new 
                    System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
                    var coverAttachment = new Attachment(stream, contentType);
                    coverAttachment.ContentDisposition.FileName = "CoverLetter.pdf";
                    emailMessage.Attachments.Add(coverAttachment);
```

But when i check the generated pdf, the texts in the {{}} are NOT getting replaced. Any idea why?

Comment: The **AcroForm** fields of a pdf have nothing to do with text in curly brackets. Your `{{FirstName}}` merely is funny looking content, not a field.

Comment: @mkl Hi Oh i see :) can you tell me how to create this acrofields in my pdf template? This is first time i hearing that term. Sorry Is this fillable form fields is actually known as acrofields?

Comment: There are two form technologies in use for pdfs, Acroform and xfa. The former one uses genuine pdf syntax and is commonly supported. The latter one uses a xml riding piggyback with the pdf, is supported by Adobe and a very few others only, and meanwhile is deprecated. I would propose you use Acroform form definitions. You can create pdf form fields on given pdfs using itext, i can try and look for examples later.

Comment: That was really useful info, i used https://www.pdfescape.com/ to generate a pdf template using form fields and now when i check stamper.AcroFields i can see my editable fields in the list. So will try with replacement and will update u